# Kubernetes sizing consideration

Tags: kubernetes

Need some understanding on sizing consideration of k8s cluster master components, in order to handle maximum 1000 pods how many master will work out and do the job specially in case of multi master mode having load balancer in front to route request to api server.

Will 3 master node(etcd, apiserver, controller, scheduler) enough to handle or require more to process the load.

Answer (score 0):

There is no strict solution for this. As per documentation in Kubernetes v. 1.15 you can create your cluster in many ways, but you must follow below rules:

- No more than 5000 nodes
- No more than 150000 total pods
- No more than 300000 total containers
- No more than 100 pods per node

You did not provide any information about infrastructure, if you want to deploy it local or in cloud.

One of advantages of cloud is that cloud kubernetes `kube-up` automatically configures the proper VM size for your master depending on the number of nodes in your cluster.

You cannot forget about provide proper `Quota` for CPU, Memory etc.

Please check [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/cluster-large/) for more detailed information.

Comment: No it is not on cloud, cluster is running on physical/virtual machine. There is enough memory/cpu for master. So 3 master are good enough to handle such number of pods.